# Getting repetition of same values multiple times while combining two queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wrote two queries in MySQL Workbench and combined them into a single query:

```
Select * 
from 
  (
    (select division.name,
            date(meter_data.reading_date),
            sum(meter_data.meter_delta) 'Gas Consumption (m3)'
     from meter, meter_data, division
     where meter.meter_id = meter_data.meter_id 
       and meter.division_id = division.division_id
       and Date(meter_data.reading_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03' 
     group by date(meter_data.reading_date) 
    ) as table1,

    (Select Date(receipt.receipt_date), 
            sum(case receipt_item.item_name 
                    when 'Gas' then receipt_item.item_amount else 0 
                end) 'Gas Purchase'
     from receipt_item, receipt
     where receipt.receipt_id = receipt_item.receipt_id
       and Date(receipt.receipt_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03'  
     group by Date(receipt.receipt_date)
    ) as table2
  );
```

When I execute the queries separately, each query returns the exactly 33 rows, but combined it returns 1089 rows. Why?

Comment: What is the combined query?

Comment: You're doing a cartesian product of `table1` and `table2`. You need to add a where clause at the end.

Comment: please see the queries i wrote

Comment: 33 x 33 = 1089 ;)

Comment: I write this where clause 
where (table1.meter_data.reading_date) = (table2.receipt.receipt_date);
but getting error unknown column name

Comment: I already mention this above 33*33=1089 how could i get only 33 rows?

Comment: Give us a fiddle as described [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) (not rextester) - a fiddle should easily be able to work for 33 rows! Take in the rest of the post also! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe You need

```
Select * 
from 
  (
    (select division.name,
            date(meter_data.reading_date) AS reading_date,
            sum(meter_data.meter_delta) 'Gas Consumption (m3)'
     from meter, meter_data, division
     where meter.meter_id = meter_data.meter_id 
       and meter.division_id = division.division_id
       and Date(meter_data.reading_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03' 
     group by date(meter_data.reading_date) 
    ) as table1,

    (Select Date(receipt.receipt_date) AS receipt_date, 
            sum(case receipt_item.item_name 
                    when 'Gas' then receipt_item.item_amount else 0 
                end) 'Gas Purchase'
     from receipt_item, receipt
     where receipt.receipt_id = receipt_item.receipt_id
       and Date(receipt.receipt_date) between '2018-04-01' and '2018-05-03'  
     group by Date(receipt.receipt_date)
    ) as table2
  )
WHERE table1.reading_date = table2.receipt_date;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT * FROM A, B` create the cartesian product where each row of A is combined with each row of B.

```
+------+------+------+------+------
| A1B1 | A1B2 | A1B3 | A1B4 | ....
+----- +------+------+------+------
| A2B1 | A2B2 | A2B3 | A2B4 | ....
+----- +------+------+------+------
| A3B1 | A3B2 | A3B3 | A3B4 | ....
+----- +------+------+------+------
| .... | .... | .... | .... | ....
```

You have to filter out what you need from the whole product. That can be done in two ways. You can use `JOIN..ON` or `JOIN..WHERE`. There is significant difference between this approaches. `JOIN..WHERE` generates the full product and then filter out only those rows that match conditions. `JOIN..ON` create the product that initially contain only pairs of rows that meet requirements.